# Prestashop 1.6.x migration; Virtual Products file location

Tags: prestashop-1.6

While migrating from Prestashop 1.6.0.11 to 1.6.1.6, I have this problem where the virtual product files are missing:

> File "xxxx" is missing:
>
> Server file name: xxxxx

I know the files are uploaded somewhere in the folder structure, changing their names, I just want to know where to be able to copy the previous uploaded files to the new version folder structure.

Where are the virtual product files uploaded?

Comment: In the `Download` folder.

Comment: If you found a solution, **post it as an answer**, do not edit your question using stuff like "SOLVED" prefixes in question titles.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED : They are located in the Download folder.  Thanks for the fast answer.